Assign condition to variable
I would like to integrate the output of a Solve. But Solve gives me an expression with some conditions. I would like to assign this condition to variables.
For example:
ysol = Solve[x^2 + y^2 + x == 1, y, Reals]

y1 = ysol[[1, 1, 2]]

Thus, y1=ConditionalExpression[-Sqrt[1 - x - x^2],  1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) < x < 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])].
I would like to automatically assign:
a = 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5])
b = 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])


a=y1[[-1, 1]]; b=y1[[-1, -1]];

To be more general, you can directly use the condition from ConditionalExpression (by accessing Last[y1] or y1[[2]]) and feed it into ImplicitRegion:
Integrate[Normal[y1], {x} ∈ ImplicitRegion[Last[y1], x]]
(* -(5 π)/8 *)

To extract the minimum and maximum, you can use MinValue and MaxValue:
{a, b} = {MinValue[{x, Last[y1]}, x], MaxValue[{x, Last[y1]}, x]}
(* {1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]), 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])} *)


Thanks, you helped me even more than I needed! But to clarify, I would like to ask another question about this ImplicitRegion. Let's suppose, I consider the following function: y1=ConditionalExpression[x,  1 < x < 2 || 5 < x < 7]. Thus, the integration you mentioned over ImplictRegion is equivalent to this expression: Integrate[x, {x, 1,2}] + Integrate[x, {x, 5,7}]?

@blahblah, yes.
